# Change axis textcolor in OxyPlot for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I like OxyPlot solution but I have one problem here.
Does anybody know how to change axis text color in WPF?
In [OxyPlot.dll](http://www.oxyplot.org/doc/API/OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis.html) there is Axis.TextColor property but this property is not present in [OxyPlot.Wpf.dll](http://www.oxyplot.org/doc/API/OxyPlot.Wpf.LinearAxis.html). I don't know why. Is there some way, how I can achieve this?

[image: Image from OxyPlots example browser]

**EDIT:**
I tried to change every axis color property I was able to find (`TicklineColor`, `MajorGridlineColor`, `MinorGridlineColor`, `ExtraGridlineColor`, `AxislineColor`, `TitleColor`) without any luck.

**EDIT2:**
As @Jamleck wants I added XAML.

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor">#ffffff</Color>
<Style x:Key="ResultPlotStyle" TargetType="oxy:PlotView">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1f1f1f" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="PlotAreaBorderColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="PlotAreaBorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ResultAxisStyle" TargetType="oxy:LinearAxis">
    <Setter Property="TicklineColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="MajorGridlineColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="MinorGridlineColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="ExtraGridlineColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="AxislineColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    <Setter Property="TickStyle" Value="None" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ResultLeftAxisStyle" TargetType="oxy:LinearAxis" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResultAxisStyle}">
    <Setter Property="PositionAtZeroCrossing" Value="True" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ResultBottomAxisStyle" TargetType="oxy:LinearAxis" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResultAxisStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TickStyle" Value="Crossing" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Not familiar with this one in particular, but bet you could find the property or the resource they reference for it by digging around in the control templates/resource dictionary.

Comment: Please post your XAML code.

Comment: OK @Jamleck I add XAML code style as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this time this property is just not implemeted in WPF version of OxyPlot yet. It clarifies why I was not able to edit this setting. As objo from developers team [answered](https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/550874) to my question, it is covered in [this](https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/workitem/9999) issue item.
So if I want this functionality in these days already I have to implement it to OxyPlot by myself.

Comment: It still seems to be not implemented, the github ticket is https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/39.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found that counter-intuitively the axis text color could be set by the TextColor property of the PlotModel-object. (Of course it will probably color more text than just your axis text - but I didn't run into that problem.)

```
MyPlotModel = new PlotModel { };
MyPlotModel.TextColor = OxyColors.Red;
```